# Adding a finite number of terms to a converging sequence results in a convergent sequence

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Suppose $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $X$ that converges to $x$ and $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ is a finite collection of points in $X$. Define a new sequence ${y_n}$ in $X$ by letting
> $y_k=\begin{cases}z_k,&1\le k\le m\\x_{k-m},&k\ge m+1\end{cases}$.
> Show that $y_n\to x$.

**my proof:**

Since $x_n\to x$, then $\forall\varepsilon >0, \exists N_1\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq N_1$. Now, consider $z_1,\ldots,z_m$ in $X$ and define $y_n$ by $y_k=z_k$ for $1\leq k\leq m$ and $y_k=x_{k-m}$ for $k\geq m+1$.

Claim $y_n\to x$. Now, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $N_2=m+N_1$. Thus, $\forall n>N_2$ so that $\forall n>m+N_1$ implies $|y_n-x|=|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ when $n>m$. Implies, $|y_n-x|<\varepsilon$ whenever $\forall n\geq m+N_1$

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Probably $|y_n-x|=|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ should read as $|y_n-x|=|x_{n-m}-x|<\epsilon$.

Comment: that might do the trick

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the proof is fine, though you don't have to repeat the definition in the question in the proof. And not all distances are absolute values. We work in a metric space $(X,d)$, I presume..

Just state: suppose $\varepsilon>0$. As $x_n \to x$ there is some $N_1 \in \Bbb N$ such that $$\forall n \ge N_1: d(x_n, x) < \varepsilon$$

Now define $N=N_1+m+1$. When $n \ge N$ we know that $n \ge m+1$ in particular so that $y_n = x_{n-m}$ where $n-m \ge N_1$ and so the previous implies directly that

$$\forall n \ge N: d(y_n, x) < \varepsilon$$

which shows convergence $y_n \to x$, as $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary.